# How do I add certain files by wildcrd to git without adding files matching the parrern in subdirectories

Tags: git, shell

I am using git (on Windows) for version control of files in some directories and source code control in others. In some directories I want to add certain files by wildcard but not files in subdirectories unless I specify that subdirectory or specific files in that directory.

I can't do it through explorer because it's dozens or  hundreds of files and I might not be able to select exactly what I'm looking for (like ?e?g*.*) but not others so I am using the command line (I have git integration insalled so if it was just certain files, I can pick them out, then right click and click "git add", but this isn't goinh to work if I have to manually go though and pick the files; thus i use the command line and wildcard selection.

I do not want to use .gitignore because there may be some subdirectories where I want some files but not others, and it could mean having to list hundreds or thousands of files. Also, I am working with more than one repo, and it would be tedious to create another .gitignore and potentially have to add dozens or hundreds of subdirectories. I tried
git add ./A* /.a*
to only add files in this directory starting with A or a, but it looks for every file starting with A or a in this directory *and all subdirectories*. I just want a simple way to say "add certain files in this directory only *and no subdirectories*" that works in any directory without having to set up, modify, or maintain a .gitignore file in every directory/project I want to repo.

I mean, is this normal behavior? That when you specify * git presumes this directory and all below? This seems ridiculous and excessive. Since when does a command automatically act on subdirectories? Is this a Linux thing? if I use
rm a*
will it recursively search every directory? I think you have to use a switch (-s) to act on subdirectories. There should be a simple way to say this, but I can't find it in the documentation for Git.

Comment: "*That when you specify * git presumes this directory and all below?*" No, it's not `git` it's `git add`. If you pass it a directory it adds all files and subdirectories recursively. To avoid that you have to list only files as `git add` arguments. Learn Linux command [`find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find), esp. its parameter `-depth 1`, it should help you to list only files.

Answer (score 1):

You observe the expected behavior :

if you have a directory named `dir`, the `d*`glob pattern will include `dir` in its expansion, and `git add dir` will add all files under `dir`.

---

One way to list files only is to use a utility which allows to list names with specific filters, such as GNU `find` :

```
find . -name 'A*' -type f -depth 1
```

will list :

- `-type f` files only
- `-name A*` whose name start with `A`
- `-depth 1` only at the current directory level

You can then use `xargs` to feed its output to `git add` :

```
find . -name 'A*' -type f -depth 1 | xargs git add
```

*note :* if you are running windows, depending on the shell you use, `find` may refer to the [`find` windows utility](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html), which doesn't do the same thing.

Choose a way to use GNU `find` instead -- for example : use `git-bash` or WSL.

Comment: `find . -name 'A*' -type f -depth 1 -exec git add '{}' \+`